# logback: possible to send an attachment with SMTPAppender?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, smtpappender

My spring boot application uses logback.

I was searching through logback docs and I couldn't find if there is support for a feature to send an email with an attachment .log file when an error occurs.

Currently my application only sends out an email with an excerpt of the error.

Comment: Afraid you'll have to inherit a SMTPAppender in your custome class, implement here required functionality and use it.

Comment: It looks to be the only possibility. I'll share code once it is done.